# How to associate alternative app to stock Gallery app when launched from stock Camera app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera, stock-android, gallery, intents

I am running Android on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo (Android KitKat 4.4.2). I would like the stock `Camera` application to launch a different application than the stock `Gallery` application when the small square icon in the upper-right hand corner of the camera screen is clicked. Presumably, the stock `Gallery` app is opened via an intent, and **I would like to associate a different app with the intent used to open the stock Galley app from the Camera app**. I tried going to `Settings -> General -> Application manager -> ALL` and for both the stock `Camera` app and the stock `Gallery` app it says that there are `No defauts set.`

The reason I would like to launch another app instead of the Gallery app from the Camera app is so that I can use an app capable of adding EXIF data (which would allow me to enter EXIF memos alongside any picture's EXIF data).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

the answer is you can't ,because the "preview" button action is hard coded in the stock camera app as a link to the right activity in the stock gallery app it sends an intent with the path to the jpeg image to the stock gallery ,the link is not an intent that can be received  by third party apps ,even if you try deleting the stock gallery app the preview button will have no action and in some phones your camera app will force close.

Comment: This is a bit dumb in my opinion. Why didn't the developers make the underlying intent behavior more general? Also, how hard would it be to download the code for the Camera app and modify that line that sends the intent. Is the Camera app distributed via a GPL license, and where can I find the code? Thanks.

Comment: yes ,I never thought of that before but now I see that this is dumb ,for the source code it depends on your phone and witch Rom/firmware you're using ,usually camera app is not delivered under GPL license but there is exceptions (if using Cyanogen roms all apps are under apache 2.0 and the source codes are available )

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I would like to submit a request to the Samsung developer team for this feature, but unfortunately all I could find was the [Android Open Source Project Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) which is not specific to Samsung or Samsung Galaxy devices. Do you know where I could submit my request? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome my friend there is two web sites of samsung's 
1 / the open source project all open sourced stuff can be found here http://opensource.samsung.com/ 
2 / the developers website http://developer.samsung.com/

you can use the contact form on the open source website or use the forum on the developers website

Comment: Yeah, there's [this site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/), but where is the page for software enhancements developer requests? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the last comment with the two links (I always tap "enter" which submits my comment before I want that :D sorry

Comment: Yes but your [first link](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy) is for developers who program to the Samsung API. I want to reach developers who code those apis as well as the stock applications so that I may make suggestions. How can I do this? Also, not all samsung stuff is open source, or is it (I know it's not GLP, but not sure if all Samsung stuff is Open Source). I was able to find the files for my [Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo GT-I9301I_EUR](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=T&menu_item=mobile&classification1=mobile_phone).

Comment: the source you found are kernel source code since it is under GPL V2 they have to put the sources public ,and some open source libraries ,submitting a feature request will take time if it was accepted (samsung is not realy that open to suggestions ) I advice the use of a third party app as a camera with the wanted option included in it or may be post a request on XDA forums may be some rom cooker will do the work for you or you can use apktool to decompile the camera apk and then made the changes you want to it.

Comment: If I decompile with `apktool` I would have to edit binary or assembly code right, I guess that's hard to do, not really feasible IMHO. And I'm not sure XDA developers would care about apps, perhaps the Cyanogenmod people, or perhaps developers on Google Play. Thanks.

Comment: if you decompile with apktool ou will have to edit smali codes witch is pretty readable if you are familiar with java ,and you will have all the .xml files readable. any way this is all I can do to help have a nice day/night